# jQuery not handling events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

[EDIT: SOLVED]

> For those that might encounter the same jQuery problem, I've been
>   using AngularJS and ui-view with states. The problem was that it
>   didn't find the button because it was dynamically created by AngularJS
>   so to solve the problem I had to move the code inside the controller
>   for that view

[/EDIT]

Good evening,

I am using a jQuery script to modify the html of an element.

```
(function($j){
  /*
  *@ Event listeners
  */
  let save_button = $j(".save-button");

  save_button.hover(function(){
    save_button.html("Save");
    console.log(this, save_button);
    }, function(){
    save_button.html('<i style="vertical-align: middle;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></i>');
  });

  console.warn("The script is loaded", $j);
})(jQuery);
```

This is the script I have written. In the index.html page I have a $.noConflict() to make sure it doesn't bother AngularJS and in this other script I pass the jQuery object inside the function and use the $j parameter inside of it.

What's written inside the script is read because the console.warn() is fired and I can see it from the console.

If I console.log jQuery or $j, it does recognize the jQuery object.

The jQuery library is correctly put in the load order, and this script is the last thing loaded by the page. I have no idea why the hover, html and even the hide functions from jQuery would not work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what happens when you console.log(save_button), outside of the `hover` method

Comment: Hello, thanks for asking. Just solved the problem. It seems that the dynamic generation of the page with angularjs is causing the problem. It wants me to put the code inside of the controller otherwise it does not know that the button exist.

Comment: good for finding the problem ! Post it as an answer yourself :D (rather than an edit) ;)

Answer (score 1):

> For those that might encounter the same jQuery problem, I've been
>   using AngularJS and ui-view with states. The problem was that it
>   didn't find the button because it was dynamically created by AngularJS
>   so to solve the problem I had to move the code inside the controller
>   for that view